# Extract previous month from the first day to the last day! SQL

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-athena

I have a column in my table with the name: efcodmov, every start of the month I need to extract all registers from the last month

end of the code:

```
AND efdtmov BETWEEN date('2023-01-01') AND date('2023-01-31')
```

How can I modify to do automatically?

Comment: Please add sample data and desired output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can compare the year and month only as follows :

```
AND date_format(efdtmov , '%Y-%m' ) = date_format ( date_add('month', -1, current_date) , '%Y-%m' )
```

Comment: Why format date instead of directly comparing dates?

Comment: The idea is to compare the previous month only no need to compare days so we format the dates to '%Y-%m'

Comment: Then use truncation functions which is better approach.

Comment: @SelVazi i have the same problem with another table, but in this case my colum that contain date is a string, how can i modify to just pick previous month:the end of my code month(cast(dt_arq as timestamp)) = 2

Comment: Not sure i understand the question, but if the date is string you could use something like : `AND date_format(efdtmov , '%Y-%m' ) = date_format ( date_add('month', -1, current_date) , '%Y-%m' )`

Comment: the guy who created the table, put the column 'efdtmov' with dtype as string, but the value is like a timestamp, i think i need to do a cast(), before use that code

Comment: Yes true, my mistake, the condition could be `AND date_format(CAST ( efdtmov AS date ), '%Y-%m' ) = date_format ( date_add('month', -1, current_date) , '%Y-%m' )`

Comment: it work, but i had to change 'date' to 'timestamp'

Answer (score 0):

Lazy way:

```sql
and efdtmov BETWEEN DATE_TRUNC('month',current_date-10) and DATE_TRUNC('month',current_date)-1
```

Assumes you run within 10 days of month's start.

More stable, but bulkier, way:

```sql
efdtmov BETWEEN DATE_TRUNC('month', DATE_TRUNC('month', current_date) -1) and DATE_TRUNC('month', current_date) - 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Use date manipulation functions, specifically [`date_trunc`](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/datetime.html#date_trunc) to truncate both dates to the same unit:

```sql
where date_trunc('month', current_date) = date_trunc('month', date_add('month', -1, current_date))
```